# build file location for sublime version 3

Tags: sublimetext3

The Sublime2 build files are located at  `\Sublime Text2\Packages\` folder, but I cannot figure out where Sublime3 put those files. Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Language.sublime-build` files (and everything else that used to be under the `Packages/Language` hierarchy) are now included in the zipped `Language.sublime-package` files found in `Sublime Text Build 3XXX/Packages/`. I haven't found an obvious way to edit these files in a cross-platform-consistent manner, so the easiest thing is to unzip the `.sublime-package` file into a folder named for that language, then move the folder to the `Sublime Text Build 3XXX/Data/Packages/` folder. As I understand it, any file in `Data/Packages/Language` will overrule whatever is contained in the corresponding `Packages/Language.sublime-package` file.

***EDIT***

For Windows *installations* (not unzipped portable installs) use the `C:\Users\YourNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` folder. The `Users` subdirectory in this folder is where all your user-specific preferences, keymaps, build systems, etc. go, similar to the `Packages\User` directory in ST2. So, if you want to unzip and modify the `Python.sublime-package` file, for example, unzip it into `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Python` and you'll be all set, as I described above.

***CLARIFICATION***

The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

<sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>

Also, instead of manually unzipping `.sublime-package` files, just use the excellent [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) utility. It does exactly what I described above without the hassle.

Comment: I didn't see the Data folder, do I need create it, if so, can I create it in AppData folder instead?

Comment: Depends on your OS, I suppose. What are you using? I have the ST2 "portable installation" unzipped in my personal directory on an XP machine here at work, as I don't have admin rights to install into `Program Files`. But, I do have admin on a Win7 box upstairs, so I can try installing there if that's what you have...

Comment: yes, I have win7, and I see Package folder in Program Files\Sublime Text 3, but I didn't see the data folder there.

Comment: I actually copied back to original folder, and it worked, but I guess it will get overwritten when I install the updates.

Comment: @J.W. - see the update to my answer above - it's `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`. Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

On OS X, `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User` works for me.

Comment: These are the user defined packages, but not the built-in packages (such as language packages). Those are located at `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages` if you use the default install location.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone runs into the same prob on a Mac and can't find the file:

I was trying to find this on a new Mac to edit my compass.sublime-build file, but couldn't find the folder. To look in ~/**Library**/Application Support/**Sublime Text 3**/**Packages**/**...** you have to press and hold the **Option** key to see the folders in bold, since it's all **hidden folders**.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a crazy workaround, but if you create a new build system, then when you save the file, you have access to the relevant folder. Before saving, you can drag unwanted files to the rubbish bin, and ones you want to read can be dragged to the file system icon in the launcher and placed somewhere where they can then be opened.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for sublime-build and heres what I got:

[image]

So for Windows, the directory for Sublime Text 3 is:

> C:\Users\horse\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User

and the Python build for Sublime 2 for example is located here:

> C:\Users\horse\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, this is the folder you which contains .sublime-build files that you created under `Tools > New build System.`

```
/home/<username>/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu then you can find your previously build files in

```
/home/your_user_name/.config/sublime-text/Packages/User
```

.config is a hidden directory, make sure you press control + h so that you can view all the hidden files and folders